# How do I install networkx 1.0 on windows?

Tags: python

I have the networkx 1.0 zip file. How do I install it on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NetworkX project [supplies binary installers for Windows](http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/networkx/?C=M;O=D) to make things easier. Download the latest executable file and install it like you would a regular application.

The zip file you have contains source. You can run setup.py but it would probably be easier to just use the binary.

Comment: There is no binary file for networkx 1.0
There is a .zip and tar.gz file

Comment: Running setup.py does not install networkx

Comment: I believe the initial development for the project is done on a Unix-based system, and ported to Windows after each release. If you need 1.0 that bad, run the setup.py file inside the zip.

Comment: The syntax to install is `python setup.py install`.

Comment: am unable to install networkx by running python setup.py install.

Comment: I get the following error
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's what the official documentation says. Maybe the python setup wasn't meant for Windows. Can you use the 0.99 exe installer?

Comment: No I need to use some functions which were defined in the new version

Comment: You need to be using Python 2.4, 2.5, or 2.6 as well.

Comment: Yes I am using Python 2.6

Comment: If you install easy_install ( http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall ) you can simply run `easy_install networkx` to attain the latest version.

Comment: You can get version 1.0rc1 here ( http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/networkx/networkx-1.0rc1.linux-i686.exe ). It says linux in the name for some reason, but it's a windows binary (exe file), and I just installed it fine.

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Many binaries are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and I guess most of them work. I have tried the binary for networkx (64 bit) and it worked.